# How to get eclipse workspace root path

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Kepler Service Release 1, I want to build java application (not plugin development).
I wish to use the path of eclipse workspace in the application. 
I tried this method

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toString();
```

but it prompts that `ResourcesPlugin cannot be resolved`, but I can't find a necessary jar file I could include to resolve this problem.

What I should do to properly getting the directory name of eclipse workspace?

**Background:**
The reason for requiring the workspace is that the java applications is developed by several developers. I have a folder containing several template files. In order to allow all developers access the folder without hard coding its path, my method is to be put in the workspace, and if I know where the workspace directory, then the java applications could be run independent where the developers put their directory. If you have a better solution, it is greatly welcome  :)

Comment: You can't use stuff in Eclipse plugins in ordinary Java programs. They expect Eclipse to be running and will fail if it is not.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks, then in ordinary Java programs, what is the proper way of getting the directory name of eclipse workspace?

Comment: You can have many workspaces on one machine so you will just have to pass the workspace as a argument to the program. Trying to do things to the workspace when you are not in a plugin is dangerous.

Comment: @greg-449 Please take a look of the background to see if that is make sense to you

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a source control system like Git or SVN, there are Eclipse plugins for many of these.

Comment: @greg-449 yes, I am currently using SVN

Answer (score 1):

If your stand-alone java application is NOT a plugin, why would it have an inherent knowledge about your eclipse workspace, unless you specifically gave it that information?

it would be possible to search for the .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs file, and that may be a good enough way of identifying an eclipse workspace, but there could easily be multiple eclipse workspaces on any given machine, and without your app being a plugin, it has no context as to which one would be linked with which eclipse instance.

Comment: I have put the reason for the necessity of workspace path, if you have a better solution, welcome to suggest :)

Comment: Having a necessary reason does not automagically transform the impossible into possible - but going by the assertion that your program will start in the eclipse workspace, then why not just use  System.getProperty("user.dir")
Alternatively, if these are just template files, why not put them into a package called "templates" and have their code import it as needed?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get project/workspace location, you can just try the following:

```
new File(".").getAbsolutePath()
```